# URL-rewriting with mod-rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How would I do this, rewrite a URL?

From

```
test.php?url=username
```

To

```
test/username/
```

I've tried this in the `.htaccess` file with no luck.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.+)$
RewriteRule /test.php$ /test/%1 [E=FILENAME:%1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to "rewrite" the request in the direction you are suggesting. You rewrite the request *from* `/test/username/` (the desired "pretty" URL) to `/test.php?url=username` (the underlying URL/file-path that actually handles the request).

You should therefore be linking to `/test/username/` in your HTML source.

Then you can use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to perform the necessary internal rewrite to convert the visible/pretty into the underlying URL/file-path your server understands. For example:

```
# Ensure that MultiViews is disabled
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/$ test.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Note that MultiViews needs to be disabled for this to work.

Note also that in `.htaccess` (a *directory* context) the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. I have also omitted the slash prefix from the *substitution* string in order to rewrite to a file-path (as opposed to a URL-path).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.+)$
> RewriteRule /test.php$ /test/%1 [E=FILENAME:%1]
> ```

This is trying to do the "opposite" and is expecting the request from the client to be of the form `/test.php?name=username` - which doesn't make sense if you are wanting the URL to "look like" `/test/username/`. You have also omitted the trailing slash on the *substitution* string (2nd argument).

You are also setting a `FILENAME` environment variable for some reason?